# what does input column in executors tab of Spark UI denote?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

what does this "input" column associated in executor tab of spark UI refers to can any one explain in brief? because I am running spark streaming application by reading data from Kafka topic where input data is 100 kb but input shows 500 MB! please help Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you move your cursor over it, you can see a tooltip explaining what it represents

> Bytes and records read from Hadoop or from Spark storage.

Comment: Yeah I have seen that but am actually reading from Kafka topic which has no more than 100KB so why does it show 300 MB ?

Comment: @MohammadUmarFarooq did you figure it out?